# URL Regex Improvement to allow localhost URL

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I have a URL validator as below

```
(^|\s)((https?:\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+\.?(:\d+)?(\/\S*)?)
```

which seems to cover most bases, but one that it can't, which is to allow localhost url's

I want to allow

```
http://localhost:8080
```

or

```
localhost:8080
```

But I don't want to allow simple string like

```
http://google
```

or

```
google
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this regex to allow `localhost` as a valid hostname:

```
(?:^|\s)((https?:\/\/)?(?:localhost|[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)+)(:\d+)?(\/\S*)?)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kIowvx/2)

Comment: Yeah the problem is that it now allows anything single string i.e. "google" but I guess I only want it optional if the first string is i.e. localhost with a port i.e. localhost:8080

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use this RegEx

```
^((https?:\/\/)?(([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)+)(:\d{1,5})?|([\w-]+:\d{1,5}))(\/\S*)?)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cPzHSA/1)